# Prevent browser resize (lock)

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I'm coding a site that uses a huge background canvas. I'm triying to lock the browser resize handlers in order to avoid scrolling issues (background out of bounds, etc.)

It's the first time i'm doing a full background site. Any advice on optimization (png size 580.72 KB 1920px x 6556px), how to get the background and elements fixed, etc will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

[Test site](http://www.liftdesignphoto.com/test/)

Comment: Rather than mess with someone's browser behavior, why not just use a wrapper div with some `max-[width|height]` CSS?

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you trying to prevent the user from resizing the browser, or do you just want to override/disable the Javascript events that fire when the resize occurs?

Comment: Never try to mess with browser behavior. The chances of fail are almost 110%.

Comment: @ErickPetru, I think that is an underestimate ;)

Comment: As a side-note, that is an amazingly cool idea for a portfolio page. :)

Comment: George, I'm trying to prevent the user from resizing the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers!   I'm going to try the wrapper to see if it works.  Any advice on the huge PNG size/load time?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea, it's a portfolio for a friend.

Comment: I tried using the max-width and height, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: this is what i'm trying to avoid http://i56.tinypic.com/2eykxz9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

are you looking something like

```
window.open(URL,name,resizable=no)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

using js or jquery disable window resize.

on load also you may try this

Comment: [W3Schools is harming the community with inaccurate information.](http://w3fools.com)